# Extracting values from xml using sql

Tags: mysql

I need to fetch the data from the xml that is stored in the database by using the sql query.
The xml is like the following

```
 <outerNode>
   <innerNode>
      <element1>Workflow1</element1>
      <element2>619</element2>
      <element3>aioperator1</element3>
      <element4>0</element4>
      <element5>623</element5>
   </innerNode>
   <innerNode>
      <element1>Workflow2</element1>
      <element2>620</element2>
      <element3>amloperator1</element3>
      <element4>1</element4>
     <element5>624</element5>
   </innerNode>
</outerNode>
```

Now, what I need to do is to get only those elements which are "aioperator1" using the MySql query.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this

```
SET @xml = '
<outerNode>
   <innerNode>
      <element1>Workflow1</element1>
      <element2>619</element2>
      <element3>aioperator1</element3>
      <element4>0</element4>
      <element5>623</element5>
   </innerNode>
   <innerNode>
      <element1>Workflow2</element1>
      <element2>620</element2>
      <element3>amloperator1</element3>
      <element4>1</element4>
     <element5>624</element5>
   </innerNode>
</outerNode>';

SELECT ExtractValue(@xml, 'outerNode/innerNode/element3') value;
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/42760)**

Comment: I want only those elements having values "aioperator1" and not all values. May be a conditional one